# Pass data from view to controller using AJAX in C# ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I have tried looking at answers to similar questions and none of them work for my code. I have tried a lot of different things, all it should do is post the fullname and then display it back in the view.
The view code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

$('#buttonDemo2').click(function () {
                var fullName = $('#fullName').val();
                var payload = {fn : fullName};
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/demo/demo2/',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(payLoad),
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#result2').html(result);
                    }
                });
            });
</script>

<fieldset>
        <legend>Demo 2</legend>
        Full Name <input type="text" id="fullName" />
        <input type="button" value="Demo 2" id="buttonDemo2" />
        <br />
        <span id="result2"></span>
</fieldset>
```

The controller code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Demo2(string fullName)
        {
            return new JsonResult("Hello " + fullName);
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ? what doesn't work ?

Comment: No errors. It only returns back "Hello" but not whatever I typed in to the form added to the end of it. E.g. it's meant to say "Hello Bob". So the value is not ever arriving at the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you pass string by ajax to action,you should ensure the received parameter name is the same as the incoming parameter name.

So, you should change `var payload = {fn : fullName};` to `var payload = {fullName: fullName};`, or change  `public IActionResult Demo2(string fullName)` to  `public IActionResult Demo2(string fn)`.

Then, because you passed only a string not an object parameter , so you don't need to use  `JSON.stringify`, and remove `contentType: 'application/json'` .

Here is the detailed code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#buttonDemo2').click(function () {
                    var fullName = $('#fullName').val();
                    var payload = { fullName: fullName }; // change name
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/demo/demo2/',
                       // contentType: 'application/json', // remove this line
                        data: payload, //remove JSON.stringify
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#result2').html(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
    </script> 
<fieldset>
    <legend>Demo 2</legend>
    Full Name <input type="text" id="fullName" />
    <input type="button" value="Demo 2" id="buttonDemo2" />
    <br />
    <span id="result2"></span>
</fieldset>
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Demo2(string fullName)
        {
            return new JsonResult("Hello " + fullName);
        }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: You Sir are a genius! Thank you so much! Yes I think the main issue was the                     
 var payload = {fn : fullName};   where the "fn" didn't match "fullName" in the controller method. You have no idea how much frustration you've saved me. Thank you a million times!